# How to Modify Existing Cookie Name or Cookie Value Stored in HTTP Cookie Manager

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have following usecase to Try:

a) Authenticate First and Get a Valid Cookie(say Cookie Name and Value is Cookie=Test123)

b) HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter Stores the Cookie

c) Send a Request with Valid Cookie from Cookie Manager, Request should go through

d) Now I want to modify either Cookie Name or Cookie Value that is Stored in JMeter Cookie Manager like Cookie=Test1234 and then Send a Request with that Cookie and Request should Fail

Point a), b) and c) it works but want to know how to accomplish Point d)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired cookie name and value in the HTTP Cookie Manager using [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Once done you can amend the variable values to whatever you want either by using [Set Variables Action plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) or any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) via [**vars** shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) like:

```
vars.put('your-variable-name', 'your-variable-value')
```

Comment: Can you share a example bean shell code which can extract particular cookie from cookie manager and modify with vars.put

Comment: Can you share a example bean shell code which can extract particular cookie from cookie manager.  I tried searching but I couldn't find a easy way to extract cookie from cookie manager. did following code which did not help much:     import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
manager.clear()
manager.remove(1)  -- Trying to remove existing cookie JCEHBDTG
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JCEHBDTG","Test","1.1.1.1","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);